# Remover Parte de String com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte String.

nomequalquer-ID 12

Quero uma expressão em PHP que remova a string -ID 12.

OBS.:O valor pode se alterar como por exemplo -ID 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar a função `strstr()` para quebrar e obter o pedaço esquerdo da string, um detalhe importante é informar o terceiro argumento que retorna a parte a esquerda, por padrão retorna a direita.

```
$str = 'nomequalquer-ID 12';
$novo = strstr($str, '-ID', true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($novo);
```